# Having trouble calculating $f_{xx}$ of a "variable-heavy" quotient.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let

$$ f(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
xy \frac{x^2 - y^2}{x^2 + y^2}, & (x,y) \ne (0,0) \\
0, & (x,y) = (0,0)
\end{cases}
$$

Compute $f_x (0,0)$, $f_y (0,0)$, $f_{xx} (0,0)$, $f_{xy} (0,0)$, and determine where it is continuous.

*Here's what I did*

First, I simplified the equation:

$$ f(x,y) = xy \frac{x^2 - y^2}{x^2 + y^2} = \frac{x^3y - xy^3}{x^2 + y^2}$$

Recallinig the definition of a partial derivative:

> $$f_x = lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h,y) - f(x,y)}{h}$$

I find that

$$f_x(0,0) = lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{(x+h)^3y - (x+h)y^3}{(x+h)^2 + y^2} - 0}{h} = 0$$

Because

$$ lim_{h \to 0} \frac{x^3y + h(...)y - xy^3 - h(y^3)}{(x^2 + h(...) + y^2)h}$$ becomes zero when $(x,y) = (0,0)$, right?

But now my concern is repeating this for $f_{xx}$. Do I repeat the operation with $f_x$ being the new $f(x,y$? Using the definition as a method? At the end I don't know if it will become 0 again. I tried it before but it becomes such a long and tedious expansion of terms.

I can't see the end in sight.

Comment: To find $f_{xx}(0,0)$ you need to find $f_x(x,y)$ for all $(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2$ first.

Comment: You shouldn't plug in for $f(x,y)$, because you'll need a function of $x$ and $y$ to take the second derivative.  If you don't substitute $f(x,y)=0$, then the leading terms will cancel and you'll be left cancelling $h$'s.

Comment: I did, it's $\frac{(3x^2y - y^3)(x^2 + y^2) - 2x(x^3y - xy^3)}{(x^2 +y^2)^2}$ and that becomes this whole process of unpacking it until what I get is a function that seems undefined when substituted for $(0,0)$

Comment: Try polar coordinates.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe how?

Comment: @Siyanda Let $x=r\cos(\phi)$ and $y=r\sin(\phi)$.

Comment: @Siyanda Please note that this function will not satisfy Euler-mixed derivative theorem. Because the function is having problem with continuity.!

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you convert it in to polar co-ordinate

Put $x=rcos(\theta)$ and $ y=rsin(\theta)$ then on simplification you will get
$f(r,\theta) = \frac {r^2}{4}sin(4\theta)$ now it will be very easy to differentiate now